# Changing the Background image based on time (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code below I change the background color based on the seconds left in the timer. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to change the background image based on the time.

I have tried to add the following:

```js
var imgArray = ['something.jpg', 'something2.jpg'];
function changeColor(){
 if (seconds <= 300 && seconds > 90) {
  document.body.style.background = imgArray[0];
 }
 else if (seconds <= 90 && seconds > 30) {
  document.body.style.background = imgArray[1];
 }
 else (seconds <= 30 && seconds >= 0) {
 document.body.style.background = imgArray[0];
 }
};
```

This however does not work. I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Below is my full code:

```js
var seconds = 300; //Variables for the code below
var countdownTimer;
var colorChange; //sets up array of colors
colorChange = ['#7ed473', '#fff194', '#fa8283', 'white']
function secondPassed(){
 var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60); //takes the output of seconds/60 and makes rounds it down. 4.7 = 4, 3.7 = 3. (to keep the minutes displaying right)
 var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; //takes remainder of seconds/60 and displays it. so 270/60 = 4.5 this displays it as 30 so it becomes 4:30 instead of 4.5
 if (remainingSeconds < 10) {  //if remaining seconds are less than 10 add a zero before the number. Displays numbers like 09 08 07 06
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds; //displays time in the html page  5:06
    document.getElementById('countdown2').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds; //displays the time a second time
   if (seconds == 0) {
  clearInterval(countdownTimer);  //keeps value at zero once it hits zero. 0:00 will not go anymore
  alert("Time is Up, Try again");
  }
};

function changeColor(){ //this changes the background color based on the time that has elapsed
 if (seconds <= 300 && seconds > 90) {  //green between 5:00 - 1:30
  document.body.style.background = colorChange[0];
 }
 else if (seconds <= 90 && seconds > 30) { //yellow between 1:30 - 30
  document.body.style.background = colorChange[1];
 }
 else if(seconds <= 30 && seconds >= 0){ // red between 30 - 0
 document.body.style.background = colorChange[2];
 }
};
 
function countdown(start){ //code for the button. When button is clicked  countdown() calls on secondPassed() to begin count down.
 secondPassed();
 if (seconds != 0) { //actual code to decrement the time
 seconds --;
 countdownTimer = setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
 changeColor();  //calls the changeColor() function so that background changes
 start.disabled = true; //disables the "start" button after being pressed
 }
 if (start.disabled = true){ //if one of the 'start' buttons are pressed both are disabled
 start2.disabled = true;
 }
};

function cdpause() { //pauses countdown
        // pauses countdown
        clearTimeout(countdownTimer);
};
    
function cdreset() {
        // resets countdown
        cdpause(); //calls on the pause function to prevent from automatically starting after reset
        secondPassed(); //reverts back to original secondPassed() function
  document.getElementById('start').disabled = false; //Enables the "start" button that has been disabled from countdown(start) function.
  document.getElementById('start2').disabled = false; //enables the 'start2' button. same as above.
  document.body.style.background = colorChange[3]; //Resets background color to white.
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newTicket2.0.css">
<script src = "Timer2.js">
</script>
</head>

<body onload = "cdreset()">
<div id = "timerBackground">
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<div id = "timerButtons">
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="countdown(this)" id = "start">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="cdpause()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="cdreset(seconds = 300)">
</div>
</div>

<div id = "timerBackground2">
<span id="countdown2" class="timer"></span>
<div id = "timerButtons2">
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="countdown(this)" id = "start2">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="cdpause()">
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="cdreset(seconds = 300)">
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is how do I get the code to change the background image rather than just changing colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the background with url(..) surrounding the value.

```
document.body.style.background = "url(" + imgArray[1] + ")";
```